# Flip flop usage during multi "START" pattern in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Test.txt file as shown below:

```
some data1 func-name1 SECTION.
data to be extracted
data to be extracted
some data2 func-name2 SECTION.
data to be extracted
data to be extracted
func-name2-EXIT. EXIT.
```

Now, I am using flip-flop operator to extract the ranges, where my START=*SECTION.* and END=*-EXIT. EXIT.* as below:

```
open FILE1, "<Test.txt" 
    or die "Cannot open File1.txt!";

open FINAL, ">Final.txt" 
    or die "Cannot open Finall.txt!";

my $START = 'SECTION.';
my $END   = '-EXIT EXIT.';

while (<FILE1>) {
    if (/$START/ .. /$END|$START/) {

        if ($_ =~ m/$END|$START/) {
            $flag = 1;
        }

        print FINAL $_;

        if ($flag == 1) {          
            print FINAL "\n\n";
            $flag = 0;
        }
    }
}
close FINAL;
close FILE1;
```

What I am trying to do is that, I need two next line as delimiters between the *SECTION.* ranges also and my Final.txt should look like as below:

```
some data1 func-name1 SECTION.
data to be extracted
data to be extracted


some data2 func-name2 SECTION.
data to be extracted
data to be extracted
func-name2-EXIT. EXIT.
```

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need flip-flop for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $first = 0;

while (<DATA>) {
    print /SECTION/ && $first++ ? "\n\n$_" : $_;
}

__DATA__
some data1 func-name1 SECTION.
data to be extracted
data to be extracted
some data2 func-name2 SECTION.
data to be extracted
data to be extracted
func-name2-EXIT. EXIT.
```

I count sections with `$first` to make sure no line breaks are inserted before the first section, but if the first section starts on line one, you can just use the special variable `$.` and replace `$first++`with `$. > 1`.

The first part of the expression `/SECTION/ && $first++` is evaluated for every line. `/SECTION/` is shorthand for `$_ =~ /SECTION/` which means that if the string `SECTION` is not found the line is printed as-is (`$_`).

If `SECTION` is found `$first++` is evaluated. Note that postfix incrementation is used because we want `$first` to evaluate to `0` (`false`) for the first section so that it's printed as-is (`$_`) and two line breaks are only prepended to following sections (`"\n\n$_"`).

Comment: I need the spacings as shown in Final.txt of my query.
This code doen't do anything like that.

Comment: @faezshingeri: What's wrong with the spacings? It looks exactly like your desired output to me.

Comment: I ain't getting the first line of SECTION. after replacement with $.>1  also

Comment: @faezshingeri: Are you saying `some data1 func-name1 SECTION.` isn't printed but everything else is as expected?

Comment: *some data1 func-name1 SECTION* is not printed only. Remaining is all fine. Also, could you please explain the code, as its a bit confuing for me?

Comment: @faezshingeri: My code can be run without changes. Do you experience other results with that exact code? I suspect the error is introduced elsewhere. I've added an explanation to the code.

Comment: If I use $first++, I get wrong output. And when I use $.>1, I get the desired output except for the first line having SECTION. ie *some data1 func-name1 SECTION*

Comment: @faezshingeri: I don't see how that's possible. Maybe you can re-post the code you have so I can have a look at it?